# Adding up total price of selected items (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, function, checkbox

I ran into a problem. Code is here:

```js
// JavaScript Document

window.totalIt= function() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += 1;
    }
  }
  if(total>=3){
    document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + (total*29).toFixed(2);
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + (total*39).toFixed(2);
  }
}

window.totalPrisDessert= function() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("dessert");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="formular">
  <div id="formulartekst">
    <form>

      <h2 class="formskrift">Order Hot Food</h2>
      <p class="kroner">$39 / $29 when 3 or more checked</p>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p1" onclick="totalIt()" /> Monday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p2" onclick="totalIt()" /> Tuesday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p3" onclick="totalIt()" /> Wednesday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p4" onclick="totalIt()" /> Thursday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p5" onclick="totalIt()" /> Friday

      <h2 class="formskrift">Dessert</h2>
      <p class="kroner">$20 ALWAYS</p>
      <input name="dessert" value="20" type="checkbox" id="p6" onclick="totalPrisDessert()"/>
      Monday<br>
      <input name="dessert" value="20" type="checkbox" id="p7" onclick="totalPrisDessert()"/>
      Tuesday<br>
      <input name="dessert" value="20" type="checkbox" id="p8" onclick="totalPrisDessert()"/>
      Wednesday<br>
      <input name="dessert" value="20" type="checkbox" id="p9" onclick="totalPrisDessert()"/>
      Thursday<br>
      <input name="dessert" value="20" type="checkbox" id="p10" onclick="totalPrisDessert()"/>
      Friday<br>

      <label>
        <br> Total
        <input value="$0.00" readonly type="text" id="total" />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Order">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0y7aoct/2/

When I check the top 5 boxes they add the price in the total box. However if I check any of the below 5 boxes (desserts) the price overwrites. I need the total price showing, but right now they are acting as two different.

Comment: You can copy paste your relevant code into your question. Check the help if you need help with formatting :)

Comment: To insert (working) code to your question you can use [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/u0y7aoct/3/)

Basically, create a common method which does the total of both

```
window.totalAll = function()
{
  document.getElementById("total").value = (totalIt() + totalPrisDessert()).toFixed(2) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to call two different function you can add both values by calling same function and just need to check a condtion whether is it product or dessert.

```
var grndTotal = 0;
var total1 = 0;
var total2 = 0;

window.totalIt= function(name) {
  if(name == "product"){

  var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].checked) {
          total += 1;
        }
      }
  if(total>=3){ total1 =  (total*29).toFixed(2);}
  else{total1 =  (total*39).toFixed(2);}
  }

if(name == "dessert"){

  var input = document.getElementsByName("dessert");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }

  total2 =  total.toFixed(2);
  }
  grndTotal = parseInt(total2) + parseInt(total1);
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$"+grndTotal ;

}
```

This is the updated function that work correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/VijayDhanvai/hd103j4a/

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you programmed it like this. You made two different function for every one of the case and these functions act separately. What did you expect? :)

You need more something like this:

```
window.totalIt = function() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  var total = 0;
    var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      count += 1;
    }   
  }   
  if(count >= 3){ 
    total = count * 29; 
  } else {
    total = count * 39; 
  }   
  return total;
}   

window.totalPrisDessert = function() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("dessert");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }   
  }   
  return total;
}   

window.grandTotal = function() {
  var total = totalIt() + totalPrisDessert();
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

Of course, use the new function `grandTotal()` in your html.